# How to send email notifications if client is second on a list in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, actionmailer

I am kinda new to Ruby on Rails and StackOverflow. I have a rails app where people can sign their names to a list. But I want to send an email notification to whoever is second in the list. How can I make this happen? Do I need an if statement? and how would I make rails know who is second?

Here is my list controller:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index
    @list = List.all.order("created_at asc")
  end

  def new
    @list = List.new
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new list_params

    if @list.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "#{@list.name}, You have been added to the List!"
    else
      render 'new', notice: "Oh No! Not Saved!"
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @list.update list_params
      redirect_to @list, notice: "#{@list.name}, has been updated!"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @list.destroy
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "#{@list.name}, has been deleted!"
  end

  private

  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :barber_id)
  end

  def find_list
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

This is my form

```
<%= form_for @list do |f| %>
  <% if @list.errors.any?%>
    <h2><%= pluralize(@list.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this list from saving:</h2>
    <ul>
      <% @list.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <%end%>
    </ul>
  <%end%>

  <div class="form-group ">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, {class: 'form-control'} %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Choose a Barber" %>
    <!-- :include_blank => true
      insert this to have the option of leaving it blank
    -->
    <div class="classic-select">
      <%= f.collection_select :barber_id, Barber.all, :id, :name %>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn-add-to-list">Submit</button>
<%end%>
```

Here is my index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 list center-block">
      <% @list.each do |list| %>
        <div class="col-md-6 names panel-default panel">
          <h1><%= link_to list.name, list %></h1>
          <p><strong>Barber:</strong> <%= list.barber.name %></p>
          <hr>
        </div>
      <%end%>
      <div class="col-md-2 center-block">
        <%= link_to "Add Me to the List", new_list_path, class: "btn-add btn"%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can get the second on your index with:

```
@list = List.all.order("created_at asc")
@second_on_list = @list.second
```

Or

```
@list = List.all.order("created_at asc")
@second_on_list = @list[1]
```

Comment: Awesome dude! Thank you so much! So now I'll just use the variable in my if statement to send my emails